# opencart 2.3 install() method not working

Tags: php, opencart2.3

I have a payment plugin which is working fine on opencart 2.0 , I tried to install it on opencart 2.3 everything works fine but there is piece of code written in the `install()` method .. but its not working on opencart 2.3.

I tried to dump in it, but nothing happen, it seems opencart2.3 is not calling my `install()` method at all.

Additional Information : 
The plugin name is Payfort and its on github https://github.com/payfort/opencart2.0-payfort
The plugin is working on both versions 2.0 & 2.3

Comment: at least tell us the name of the plugin

Comment: Payfort , its on github too
[link](https://github.com/payfort/opencart2.0-payfort)

Comment: Its working on both versions 2.0 & 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart 2.3 folder structure is different from 2.0 for example your payment folders are catalog/controller/extension/payment in 2.3 and in 2.0 it is catalog/controller/payment. The "extension" is added on later versions.
$this->load->language('extension/payment/????') will also be different as the folder structure changed. So it most probably not calling the correct public function.
Contact the author of the plugin to change/update the plugin. If it the payment is directed to a Payment Gateway for instance paypal or payfast. 
If you have written the plugin your self. You can use the PP_Standard module to duplicate and rewrite a custom plugin. 
https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=136&t=30653

Hopes this helps.

Comment: I know about opencart 2.3 structure & have fixed this issue for my plugin .
My plugin is for Payfort payment gateway which is new plugin , I think there is a bug on version 2.3 , when the user install the plugin there is a method called `install()` with it I can do something after install has finished, this part is not working for me.

Comment: beside all payment plugins in Opencart 2.3 are not using `install()` method at all.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCart 2.3.0.2 the install method of class ControllerExtensionExtensionPayment (placed in: admin/controller/extension/extension/payment.php) is called when a payment extension is installed.

In this method the install method of the payment's controller is called:

```
// Call install method if it exsits
$this->load->controller('extension/payment/' . $this->request->get['extension'] . '/install');
```